# How to do group by 2 column and performe count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to performe count like this query in pandas?

```
Select col1, col2, count(col3) as total from table
GROUP by col1,col2
```

Comment: See [Comparison with SQL](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#comparison-with-sql) from the docs.

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'col3': 'total'})`

Answer (score 1):

You want the pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index = False).count()
```

This will give you a count of all your other columns. If you want to specify a different aggregation function for each column, you can use `.agg`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index = False).agg({'col3': 'count', 'col4': 'sum'})
```

Comment: still got different result from my query result